# Performing a hypothesis test with a difference-in-differences study in STATA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, stata, difference-in-difference

I am trying to write a research method which includes a difference-in-differences study. I survey people's exam results in England & Scotland at t=0, t=1. The mean values of the results are:

- t=0, England - A
- t=0, Scotland - B
- t=1, England - C
- t=1, Scotland - D

This would give a causal effect of (A-C)-(B-D) for the DiD study, however, I want to confirm whether this result would be statistically significant at 5%. I'm looking at forming a hypothesis test where:

H0: (A-C)-(B-D) = 0

H1: (A-C)-(B-D) ≠ 0

The observations in each category are n=100 (400 total observations). Does anyone know the appropriate way to test this significance of this study without using just dummy variables for time and area and using linear regression? I'm hoping to use STATA but if anyone knows R better then that would be appreciated too.